# Casting a borrowed reference with a lifetime to a raw pointer in Rust

Tags: rust, jnienv, raw-pointer

I am new to rust and am trying to wrap my head around lifetimes. Please consider the following code:

```rust
use jni::JNIEnv;

pub struct CameraAppEngine<'a> {
    _env: &'a JNIEnv<'a>,
    _width: i32,
    _height: i32
}

impl<'a> CameraAppEngine<'a> {
    pub fn new(_env: &'a JNIEnv<'a>, _width: i32, _height: i32) -> CameraAppEngine {
        CameraAppEngine { _env, _width, _height }
    }

    pub fn env(&'a self) -> JNIEnv<'a> {
        JNIEnv::from_raw(self._env).unwrap() // error!
    }
}
```

The JNIEnv::from_raw method has a type signature of `from_raw(ptr: *mut JNIEnv) -> Result<Self>`, so this results in the compile error:

```
|         JNIEnv::from_raw(self._env).unwrap()
|                          ^^^^^^^^^ types differ in mutability
|
= note: expected raw pointer `*mut *const jni::sys::JNINativeInterface_`
                found reference `&'a jni::JNIEnv<'a>`
```

I then tried `JNIEnv::from_raw(self._env as *mut JNIEnv<'a>).unwrap()`, but this results in:

```
|         JNIEnv::from_raw(self._env as *mut JNIEnv<'a>).unwrap() // error!
|                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected *-ptr, found struct `jni::JNIEnv`
|
= note: expected raw pointer `*mut *const jni::sys::JNINativeInterface_`
            found raw pointer `*mut jni::JNIEnv<'a>`

error[E0606]: casting `&'a jni::JNIEnv<'a>` as `*mut jni::JNIEnv<'a>` is invalid
--> native_app/src/camera_engine.rs:16:26
|
|         JNIEnv::from_raw(self._env as *mut JNIEnv<'a>).unwrap() // error!
|                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

How do I get a valid JNIEnv out of the reference in the struct?

Cheers and thank you for your time!

**Update**

Here is a less contrived way to demonstrate the prolem.

```rust
pub fn create_camera_session(&'a mut self, surface: jobject) {
    // error!
    let window = ffi::ANativeWindow_fromSurface(self._env as *mut JNIEnv<'a>, surface);
}
```

This results in:

```
error[E0606]: casting `&'a jni::JNIEnv<'a>` as `*mut jni::JNIEnv<'a>` is invalid
```

The type signature of ANativeWindow_fromSurface is `ANativeWindow_fromSurface(env: *mut JNIEnv, surface: jobject) -> *mut ANativeWindow`.

Comment: I'm completely inexperienced with `jni`, but that usage of `from_raw` looks extraordinarily sketchy to me. Do you need to store a reference rather than just an owned `JNIEnv<'a>`? Even if you do store a reference, could you just use `Clone` instead of `from_raw` and avoid the risk of `unsafe`?

Comment: Ugg, you're totally right. I was over complicating things. Simply `pub fn env(&'a self) -> &'a JNIEnv<'a> { self._env }` would suffice. If you want to post up an answer I will mark it accepted. Cheers!

Comment: I actually still do need to know how to cast it to a raw pointer unfortunately. For example, when calling `ANativeWindow_fromSurface(env: *mut JNIEnv, surface: jobject) -> *mut ANativeWindow` I get the same problem. There are a lot of ffi bindings which expect a raw pointer.

Comment: Ah, well, I'm glad you finally got the answer you needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types named `JNIEnv` in the `jni` crate:

1. [`jni::sys::JNIEnv`](https://docs.rs/jni/0.14.0/jni/sys/type.JNIEnv.html): This is a type alias: `type JNIEnv = *const JNINativeInterface_;`
2. [`jni::JNIEnv`](https://docs.rs/jni/0.14.0/jni/struct.JNIEnv.html): This is a safe wrapper around `jni::sys::JNIEnv`.

You cannot simply use `as` to cast between the two, because they are unrelated types. In fact, in your `env()` method, you can just clone `self._env`. Furthermore, `jni::JNIEnv` is just a wrapper for a pointer, and cloning is cheap (it's not a deep copy), so you can store it by value rather by reference in `self._env`.

`jni::JNIEnv` exposes methods to convert between the two types. [`jni::JNIEnv::from_raw`](https://docs.rs/jni/0.14.0/jni/struct.JNIEnv.html#method.from_raw) goes from `jni::sys::JNIEnv` to `jni::JNIEnv`, and [`jni::JNIEnv::get_native_interface`](https://docs.rs/jni/0.14.0/jni/struct.JNIEnv.html#method.get_native_interface) goes the other way.

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I needed. Many thanks!

Comment: Oh no! It's actually much worse than I thought. There is a third unrelated `JNIEnv` type, and that is the one defined in the ffi bindings, and has completely different method signatures. I posted a follow up here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60242423/rust-converting-jnisysjnienv-to-jninativeinterface-defined-in-ffi