# Converting jni::sys::JNIEnv to JNINativeInterface defined in ffi

Tags: rust, java-native-interface, ffi, jnienv

I am following up on [Casting a borrowed reference with a lifetime to a raw pointer in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60216847/casting-a-borrowed-reference-with-a-lifetime-to-a-raw-pointer-in-rust), which solved the wrong problem.

Please consider the following code:

```rust
extern crate jni;
extern crate ffi;

use jni::JNIEnv;
use jni::objects::JClass;
use jni::sys::{jint, jlong, jobject};

struct CameraAppEngine {
    _env: *mut jni::sys::JNIEnv,
    _width: i32,
    _height: i32
}

impl CameraAppEngine {
    pub fn new(_env: *mut jni::sys::JNIEnv, _width: i32, _height: i32) -> CameraAppEngine {
        CameraAppEngine { _env, _width, _height }
    }

    pub fn create_camera_session(&mut self, surface: jobject) {
        // error!
        let window = ffi::ANativeWindow_fromSurface(self._env, surface);
    }
}

fn app_engine_create(env: &JNIEnv, width: i32, height: i32) -> *mut CameraAppEngine {
    let engine = CameraAppEngine::new(env.get_native_interface(), width, height);
    Box::into_raw(Box::new(engine))
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn Java_io_waweb_cartoonifyit_MainActivity_createCamera(env: JNIEnv<'static>, _: JClass, width:jint, height:jint) -> jlong {
    app_engine_create(&env, width, height) as jlong
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn Java_io_waweb_cartoonifyit_MainActivity_onPreviewSurfaceCreated(_: JNIEnv, _: JClass, engine_ptr:jlong, surface:jobject) {
    let mut app = unsafe { Box::from_raw(engine_ptr as *mut CameraAppEngine) };
    app.create_camera_session(surface);
}
```

And in the `ffi` crate we have:

```rust
extern "C" {
    pub fn ANativeWindow_fromSurface(env: *mut JNIEnv, surface: jobject) -> *mut ANativeWindow;
}
```

This results in:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
--> native_app/src/lib.rs:24:53
|
|         let window = ffi::ANativeWindow_fromSurface(self._env, surface);
|                                                     ^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `ffi::JNINativeInterface`, found struct `jni::sys::JNINativeInterface_`
|
= note: expected raw pointer `*mut *const ffi::JNINativeInterface`
            found raw pointer `*mut *const jni::sys::JNINativeInterface_`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
--> native_app/src/lib.rs:24:64
|
|         let window = ffi::ANativeWindow_fromSurface(self._env, surface);
|                                                                ^^^^^^^ expected enum `std::ffi::c_void`, found enum `jni::sys::_jobject`
|
= note: expected raw pointer `*mut std::ffi::c_void`
            found raw pointer `*mut jni::sys::_jobject`
```

The problem is that the JNIEnv type expected by `ANativeWindow_fromSurface` is actually unrelated to `jni::sys::JNIEnv` entirely.

It's defined in `ffi` like so:

```rust
pub type JNIEnv = *const JNINativeInterface;
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub struct JNINativeInterface {
    pub reserved0: *mut ::std::os::raw::c_void,
    pub reserved1: *mut ::std::os::raw::c_void,
    pub reserved2: *mut ::std::os::raw::c_void,
    pub reserved3: *mut ::std::os::raw::c_void,
    pub GetVersion: ::std::option::Option<unsafe extern "C" fn(arg1: *mut JNIEnv) -> jint>,
    pub DefineClass: ::std::option::Option<
        unsafe extern "C" fn(
            arg1: *mut JNIEnv,
            arg2: *const ::std::os::raw::c_char,
            arg3: jobject,
            arg4: *const jbyte,
            arg5: jsize,
        ) -> jclass,
    >,
    pub FindClass: ::std::option::Option<
        unsafe extern "C" fn(arg1: *mut JNIEnv, arg2: *const ::std::os::raw::c_char) -> jclass,
    >,
    pub FromReflectedMethod:
        ::std::option::Option<unsafe extern "C" fn(arg1: *mut JNIEnv, arg2: jobject) -> jmethodID>,
    pub FromReflectedField:
        ::std::option::Option<unsafe extern "C" fn(arg1: *mut JNIEnv, arg2: jobject) -> jfieldID>,
    pub ToReflectedMethod: ::std::option::Option<
        unsafe extern "C" fn(
            arg1: *mut JNIEnv,
            arg2: jclass,
            arg3: jmethodID,
            arg4: jboolean,
        ) -> jobject,
    >
    // etc...
}
```

Given the glue code shown in the example, how do I get a valid reference to `ffi::JNIEnv` so that I may pass it to the `ANativeWindow_fromSurface` method. Bonus points if you give advice on converting `jni::sys::jobject` to `*mut std::os::raw::c_void` (lifetime concerns, null pointers, etc.).

[Full source to ffi definitions](https://github.com/drkstr101/CartoonifyIt/blob/612412f52e29b20dd226b84c4788627377438e4b/native_app_sys/src/ffi_arm.rs#L841)

Here is the basic helloworld implementation I used to prove the concept in the accepted answer:

```rust
use std::ffi::{CString, CStr};
use std::os::raw::{c_char};

/// Expose the JNI interface for android below
#[cfg(target_os="android")]
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
pub mod android {
    extern crate ffi;

    use super::*;
    use self::ffi::{JNIEnv, jclass, jstring, jlong};


    #[derive(Debug)]
    struct AppEngine {
        greeting: *mut c_char
    }

    unsafe fn rust_greeting(app: *mut AppEngine) -> *mut c_char {
        let app = Box::from_raw(app);
        app.greeting
    }

    /// Constructs an AppEngine object.
    fn rust_engine_create(to: *const c_char) -> *mut AppEngine {
        let c_str = unsafe { CStr::from_ptr(to) };
        let recipient = match c_str.to_str() {
            Err(_) => "there",
            Ok(string) => string,
        };

        let greeting = CString::new("Hello ".to_owned() + recipient).unwrap().into_raw();

        let app = AppEngine{greeting: greeting};
        Box::into_raw(Box::new(app))
    }

    /// Destroys an AppEngine object previously constructed using `rust_engine_create()`.
    unsafe fn rust_engine_destroy(app: *mut AppEngine) {
        drop(Box::from_raw(app))
    }

    #[no_mangle]
    pub unsafe extern fn Java_io_waweb_cartoonifyit_MainActivity_greeting(env: &mut JNIEnv, _: jclass, app_ptr: jlong) -> jstring {
        let app = app_ptr as *mut AppEngine;
        let new_string = env.as_ref().unwrap().NewStringUTF.unwrap();
        new_string(env, rust_greeting(app))
    }

    #[no_mangle]
    pub unsafe extern fn Java_io_waweb_cartoonifyit_MainActivity_createNativeApp(env: &mut JNIEnv, _: jclass, java_pattern: jstring) -> jlong {
        let get_string_chars = env.as_ref().unwrap().GetStringChars.unwrap();
        let is_copy = 0 as *mut u8;
        rust_engine_create(get_string_chars(env, java_pattern, is_copy) as *const c_char ) as jlong
    }

    #[no_mangle]
    pub unsafe extern "C" fn Java_io_waweb_cartoonifyit_MainActivity_destroyNativeApp(_: JNIEnv, _: jclass, app_ptr: jlong) {
        let app = app_ptr as *mut AppEngine;
        rust_engine_destroy(app)
    }
}
```

This is just a proof of concept. More care should be taken when casting raw pointers about. Also see notes about `Box::leak` in the accepted answer.

Comment: Am I correct in guessing that this is on android?

Comment: In principal `ffi::JNINativeInterface`, and `jni::sys::JNINativeInterface_` are the same struct and therefore you should be able to cast between them without causing segfaults. However I'm curious why you are using the jni crate in the first place? It appears that the ffi has all the types you need? Lastly the jni crate was not intended for use with android afaik.

Comment: Perhaps I don't actually need `jni` crate. This is what was used by all the examples showing android/rust interop. EG `Java_io_waweb_cartoonifyit_MainActivity_createCamera` gets passed a JNIEnv automatically. Perhaps I will try changing this type to ffi::JniEnv and see what happens. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @PiRocks Yes this is an an android app. Specifically, I am attempting to port the [texture-view](https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/tree/master/camera/texture-view/) NDKCamera sample app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `JNIEnv` is a pointer to a struct used for communication between Java and native code. This communication ABI is implemented by pretty much every JVM(and android). There are multiple versions of the aforementioned structs, which is what the `GetVersion` field is for.

It seems to me that you are using an external `jni` crate along with your own `ffi` crate generated from this [wrapper](https://github.com/drkstr101/CartoonifyIt/blob/612412f52e29b20dd226b84c4788627377438e4b/native_app_sys/wrapper.h). I would expect your `ffi` crate to be the most correct since it is using android headers, instead of the standard JVM headers which a most likely being used by the `jni` crate.

One last note `Box::from_raw(engine_ptr as *mut CameraAppEngine)`, creates a box which will free the memory located at `engine_ptr`. This is likely not what you want. Consider using `Box::leak` to leak the created `Box` and avoid use after frees.

Comment: [this](https://github.com/drkstr101/CartoonifyIt/commit/d42c7dcc850a192e1b05b400770548e432ca1172) is where I'm stuck. Before commit the hello, world app runs as expected (with `jni` crate). Using symbols from ffi complains that `GetStringChars` is a field and not a method. I'm not even really sure how to call these methods, let alone what happens at runtime when I inject my own `JNIEnv` type into the method signature.

Comment: Well I got a little closer with [this](https://github.com/drkstr101/CartoonifyIt/commit/15449130b26bc539c33d37eaf80122809b0ca711), so now I just need to figure out things like "expected raw pointer `*const u8`, found raw pointer `*const u16`". At least I'm getting closer. I will mark accepted once I can use `ffi:JNIEnv` in my helloworld example.

Comment: [Victory!](https://github.com/drkstr101/CartoonifyIt/blob/3ba4080440b94ad79cb4e601f7589d0b207ab8ad/native_app/src/lib.rs). It's a little bit difficult working with all the raw types, but `ffi::JNIEnv` totally works as a drop in replacement for `jni::JNIEnv`. Many thanks to you, sir!

Comment: I assume you already figured it out, but `GetStringChars` is a function pointer in a field. See https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/function-pointer.html for more information.

Comment: Yup, I was missing an extra `unwrap()`. Also the first param wasn't a `&self`, I had to pass in a `&mut JNIEnv` instead. I posted the full proof of concept above if you're interested. Thanks again for the help!